# Adicionar e remover classes ao clicar Jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde, gostaria de adicionar e remover as classes "active" ao clicar em cada opção, e mostrar o conteúdo de cada um, segue o [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e1dgsj6u/11/) de exemplo. Obrigado

Html:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a class="active">Opção 1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="">Opção 2</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="content active">Mostrar conteúdo 1</div>
<div class="content">Mostrar conteúdo 2</div>
```

Css:

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma

**Html**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="active">Opção 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="">Opção 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content active">Mostrar conteúdo 1</div>
<div class="content">Mostrar conteúdo 2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function(i){
        $('ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.content').each(function(index) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Ao clicar ele remove o 'active' de todos os 'a' e alterna entre os conteúdos.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/e1dgsj6u/70/

> Fiz de tudo para não alterar o html e o css, esta funcionando, mas
>   seria bom colocar um identificador para cada conteúdo que você queira
>   mostra, porque desta forma vai funcionar apenas com dois elementos.

Utilizando data para identificação

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="active" data-id='1'>Opção 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="" data-id='2'>Opção 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content active" data-id='1'>Mostrar conteúdo 1</div>
<div class="content" data-id='2'>Mostrar conteúdo 2</div>
```

Coloquei um data-id para identificar o seu relacionamento

**CSS**

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

O mesmo css

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function(){
        $('ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.content').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var id = $(this).data('id');    
        var content = $('.content').filter(function() { 
            return $(this).data("id") == id 
        });    
        content.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Assim a ação é realizada de acordo com o seu identificador, assim você pode criar novos elementos sem preocupar em alterar o jquery.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/e1dgsj6u/72/

Comment: É que eu quero mostrar outro conteúdo em cada div.

Comment: vou editar e colocar da forma que você quer

Comment: Eu alterei como você pediu.

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de executar .hide e .show e nem do uso de hasClass, quando na necessidade do autor talvez o toggleClass já resolveria

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pela dica, fiz a alteração ;)

Answer (score 3):

O Toggleclass já faz isso por você, segue um exemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>toggleClass demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .blue {
    color: blue;
  }
  .highlight {
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="blue">Click to toggle</p>
<p class="blue highlight">highlight</p>
<p class="blue">on these</p>
<p class="blue">paragraphs</p>

<script>
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função addClass() e removeClass()

```
$(elemento).addClass('someClass')
$(elemento).removeClass('someClass')
```

Comment: $(elemento).toggleClass('someClass') funciona melhor

Answer (score 0):

Como a lista está separada das `div`s, é preciso criar alguma vinculação de uma `<li>` com cada `div`. Para isso você pode colocar as `div`s dentro de uma `div` *container*. Assim você pode vincular o index de cada `li` com o index de cada `div` dentro do *container*. Ou seja, a `li` de índice `0` se refere à `div` de índice `0` e assim por diante.

> Você poderia também criar atributos `id`s para cada `div`, mas isso inflaria o HTML com mais código desnecessário.

Para trocar a classe dos elementos você pode usar `toggleClass` e mostrar/ocultar as `div`s pelo seu índice, conforme explicado antes:

```js
$(function(){
   
   $("ul li").click(function(){
      
      var idx = $(this).index();
      
      $(this)
      .parent()
      .find("li a")
      .removeClass("active");
      
      $("a", this)
      .toggleClass("active");
      
      $("div", "#container")
      .removeClass("active")
      .eq(idx)
      .addClass("active");
      
   });
   
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <a class="active">Opção 1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="">Opção 2</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="container">
   <div class="content active">Mostrar conteúdo 1</div>
   <div class="content">Mostrar conteúdo 2</div>
</div>
```